# Creating relationships in Power BI when there are no columns with unique data

Tags: database, powerbi, foreign-keys

I'm new to the data world and trying to get started. I have imported 2 tables to power BI. They have common columns but none of the rows are unique. Even when merging up to 7 columns a many-many connection is still created. I am trying to get a 1-1 or 1-many join, as I have been told it's best practice. I'm at a bit of a loss on what to do.

So if I'm understanding the logic correctly, no unique rows means no PK, and only many-many relationships can be created.

I've tried to create unique rows by merging up-to 7 columns, but still some of the rows aren't unique.

Any other work around? I appreciate all help

Comment: It all depends on what the tables represent and why there are duplicate rows.  Sometimes you eliminate dups.  Sometimes you add an index column.  Sometimes you generate a new unique column with COMBINEVALUES.  You'd need to post and describe some sample data for anywone to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "Dimension" table in between. Pick one common column, extract it from the table and filter for unique/disinct values. (You could also combine this column from both tables in case they don't have all the same values. This is the one side of the relationship. Now you connect to the common columns of both "Fact" tables, which become the many side of the relationship. This allows you to filter from Dim to both Facts. Avoid using bidirectional fitering.